# slf4j.Logger does not show value

Tags: java, slf4j

Why the value 12 doesnt appear?

Code:

```
logger.info("height", 12);
```

Stacktrace:

```
13:41:29.022 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO com.math.pro.ak.fragment.dashboard.LoginController - height
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.math.pro.ak" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: use `logger.info("height {}", 12);` or `logger.info("height" +12);` to print 12.

Comment: I've updated answer with detailed explanation , go through it for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you intended to use [parameterized logging](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance):

```
logger.info("height: {}", 12);
```

Or you could just pass in one argument (though as the linked documentation states, using parameterized messages can perform better):

```
logger.info("height: " + 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by me in the comment, you were not calling the `logger.info()` properly. `Logger.java` is an interface in the `slf4j` and if you notice there are overloaded methods for `info` methods.

[Refer Logger interface info methods](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String)).

From  `Logger.java` interface. when you call `logger.info("height " + 12);` then below method, which takes `String` will be called.

```
    /**
     * Log a message at the INFO level.
     *
     * @param msg the message string to be logged
     */
    public void info(String msg);
```

And when you call `logger.info("height {}", 12);` below **overloaded** method will be called.

```
    /**
     * Log a message at the INFO level according to the specified format
     * and argument.
     * <p/>
     * <p>This form avoids superfluous object creation when the logger
     * is disabled for the INFO level. </p>
     *
     * @param format the format string
     * @param arg    the argument
     */
    public void info(String format, Object arg);
```

**Important** :- You should always use the second method `info(String format, Object arg)`, As mentioned in the javadoc comment of method **This form avoids superfluous object creation when the logger is disabled for the INFO level**(it internally check whether given log level is enabled or not, before creating objects). Hence you will save both cpu and memory, when INFO level is disabled but in case of first method as its given **String** in the method will always be created irrespective of logger level.

Above optimization is specially useful when you are using the `logger.debug()`. As most of the time your application would be running at the **INFO** level and you don't have to explicitly check `if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {` condition, to save the cpu and memory.